# How to use $this in mysqli connection ?

Tags: php, mysqli

i declare mysqli connections in **connections.php** . i declare **$this->connection** instead of **$connect** since i want to separate each functions in one file.

```
<?php
$this->connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","itdforum");

        if(mysqli_connect_errno){
            echo "Failed to connect to MYSQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
?>
```

i'm trying to use the **$this-connection** in other functions

```
<?php
include("connections.php");
    function getSome(){

        $get_some = "SELECT * FROM table"
        $run_some = mysqli_query($this->connection, $get_some);
    }
?>
```

but error show as below

```
Using $this when not in object context in localhost\connections.php
```

anyone knows how to fix it ? or i just add all the functions into one php file only ? thanks.

Comment: Agree with millinon's answer: if you want to use "$this" you would need to create a wrapping class.  Likely it would be a utility type class which manges the overall Database interaction.  You could also use $GLOBALS['database'] to store the connection pointer instead of $this if you'd rather keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a class:

```php
class Thing {
    function __construct(){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(...)
        if(mysqli_connect_errno){
            echo "Failed to connect to MYSQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    }

    function getSome(){
        $get_some = "SELECT * FROM table"
        $run_some = mysqli_query($this->connection, $get_some);
    }

}
```

To use it:

```php
include('Thing.php');

$thing = new Thing();

$thing->getSome();
```

Comment: thanks for the response . Where to add $thing = new Thing(); ? is it inside of each function or outside function ? thanks btw :)

Comment: `$thing = new Thing();` is resources allocation, so you should put it wherever it makes sense for setup to be. You probably only want to do it once, so it should probably be outside a function.